# Trimming / cropping a movie file?

Tags: video-editing, quicktime

Now, I'm not really sure what's the exact term here. As far as I saw, cropping is related to video size.

I need a program to trim some parts of the video file. On a timescale, for example, from 0-60s, I'd like to trim the parts from 14-20s, and from 30-35s.

Can anyone give a recommendation for such an application ?

The movie in question is a .MOV file, so Windows Movie Maker doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it can handle .MOV files, but have you tried [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/)?

Otherwise you can always convert the .MOV file first with [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html).

Actually, with that last one, you can also "trim" parts of a movie (like you describe).

Comment: No, VirtualDub won't do MOV files: http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=129207

Answer (score 4):

[QuickTime Pro](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/pro/) will work great for this. It's an additional ~$30 purchase on top of QuickTime for Windows or Mac. If you have access to a Mac and can wait a few weeks until it's released,  [OS X 10.6](http://www.apple.com/macosx/), aka [Snow Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_v10.6), is [reported](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/02/latest-snow-leopard-seeds-incorporate-quicktime-pro-features.ars) to have the functionality of QuickTime Pro built-in.

Comment: If you have access to a Mac, you can also do this in iMovie.

Comment: Quicktime Pro does it without re-coding. iMovie has to encode the whole movie again.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [AVIDemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) .  The user interface is extremely quick to learn and the input/output filters are really straightforward and easy to use.   Just drag a video file into the window, set the start and end locations of your video if you are doing a 'crop', then , on the left side of the app choose the re-encode video and audio format (or you can choose a straight copy of original format into your new container type) from the dropdowns.   You can also easily add a filter such as "rotate 90 degrees" and then use the "Save As" to start processing your translated video.   :

> Avidemux is a free video editor designed for simple cutting, filtering
>   and encoding tasks. It supports many file types, including AVI, DVD
>   compatible MPEG files, MP4 and ASF, using a variety of codecs. Tasks
>   can be automated using projects, job queue and powerful scripting
>   capabilities.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Trial Version of Sony Vegas Movie Studio or Sony Vegas Pro would probably be the easiest way out. Just go in the timeline and press S to slice video. Alternatively you could use Adobe Premiere (CS5 is allegedly very good now) or any other decent NLE. Make sure your project resolution and frame rate matches your .MOV clip.

You can also use Avisynth which is a fantastic tool but not exactly user friendly.
http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page

Microsoft's Expression Encoder 3 is a free and quite elegant VC-1 encoding / trimming tool also (use Mark in / Mark Out in the timeline). It takes .mov as input without any issues.

All of the above involve reencoding your footage.